# Best Practice: Using Java 8 Optional or throwing Exception

Tags: java, exception, option-type

Java 8 has introduced `Optional` API to denote values which could be `null` at runtime. In the following cases is it best to throw a checked exception or return a `Optional` return type to represent edge case?

Case 1: Returning type `Optional`

```
private Optional<Item> getItem(String itemName)
{
    for (Item item : items)
    {
        if (item.getName().equals(itemName))
            return Optional.of(item);
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Case 2: Throwing checked exception

```
  private Item getItem(String itemName) throws ItemNotFound
   {
        for (Item item : items)
        {
            if (item.getName().equals(itemName))
                return item;
        }

        throw new ItemNotFound();
   }
```

As Martin Fowler advocates, `Optional`/Special case pattern is a better practice but in this simple scenario throwing a checked exception does the job too.

Which one should I be following?

Comment: Neither, all these `null`-safe types are just a big overhead, return `null`, and document the method that the result may be `null`. I don't see a big advantage in `if(resultOptional.isPresent())` over `if(result == null)`, but this just may be my opinion. Also `exceptions` should, again IMO, only be thrown in extreme cases

Comment: @AxelH Sorry I fixed my code sample. It was supposed to be `throw new ItemNotFound()`

Comment: An exception should be use for exceptional case, so is it an expected feature or not ? If it is, then you don't want an exception, you can return `null` or the `Optional`. There is no "good way"

Comment: Downvoter please explain the reason

Comment: @Lino Optional exists is to provide a way to express nullability in code, not documentation. It exists so that we don't have to remember to document the nullability. Also, let's talk about overhead only after we have identified Optional to be a performance bottleneck. At this moment it is just premature optimization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This basically boils down to: Does it make sense for this use-case for item to be missing?

Lets say say an app has users. User can add a phone number to his account info. As his prone number does not have to be there, you can use optional. Phone number might be there but might be missing. Client code has to handle Optional/nullable value.

On the other hand if I want to look at his email, which is a mandatory during registration. Then the exception is the way to go. Email must be there, but is not. Here client code faces invalid application state/corrupted user.

Comment: Thanks. This makes the most sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

- If null is an error condition, then throw an exception.
- If null is a valid return value, then return an empty Optional.